# BibTex/Natbib: References with exactly three authors require all authors on first occurence and first author et al on further occurences

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I'm writing a paper for a journal (MNRAS, the UK Royal Astronomical society journal) which requires that when I cite any papers with exactly three authors, I need to give the full author list at the first citation, but merely give first author et al on any further citations.

e.g. for an example, for a reference to a paper by Bloggs, Smith and Klein 1999 with a cite key of Bloggs1999, I want to be able to type into my latex file the following:

```
This information was found within \citet{Bloggs1999}. Referring again 
to this seminal paper \citep{Bloggs1999}.
```

And have this be typeset after running latex/bibtex/latex/latex as:

```
This information was found within Bloggs, Smith and Klein (1999). 
Referring again to this seminal paper (Bloggs et al. 1999).
```

The journal provided class and .bib file (mn2e.cls and mn2e.bst) don't support this (and mn2e.bst has a bunch of other problems anyway) unfortunately. I know that natbib lets you do this manually, with `\citet` and `\citet*`,  but I was looking for something automatic, if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proof of concept (no support for the optional argument, and something similar is needed for `\citep` and other cite commands), and also it assumes that the `.bst` style use "et al" for references for more that a single author.

The idea is to create something similar to `\ifciteseen` in `biblatex`. Thus we can create a  list of references already cited in the document (and we exploit the list facilities of `etoolbox`).  Then, if the  reference has not been used before we use `\citet*`, and we add the key to the list of seen references. Otherwise, we use `\citet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B and Cuthor, C and Duthor, D},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = 2013
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B and Cuthor, C and Duthor, D},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = 2012
}
\end{filecontents}


\newcommand{\citelist}{}

\newcounter{currentcite}
\newcounter{currentcitetotal}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{
  \setcounter{currentcitetotal}{0}
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\addtocounter{currentcitetotal}{1}}
  \docsvlist{#1}
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{currentcite}{1}%
  \ifinlist{##1}{\citelist}
    {\citet{##1}}
    {\citet*{##1}\listadd{\citelist}{##1}}%
  \ifnumcomp{\value{currentcitetotal}}{>}{\value{currentcite}}
    {, }
    {}%
  }
  \docsvlist{#1}
}


\begin{document}

\mycite{test1,test2}

\mycite{test1}

\mycite{test2}


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]